# Quiero determinar si un string dado es palíndromo/capicúa o no pero no funciona y me dice siempre que no

Tags: c#, string

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una palabra para determinar si es palíndromo o no");
    string p = Console.ReadLine();
    bool palindromo = true;

    for (int j = p.Length-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      char jletras = Convert.ToChar(p[j]);

      string pAlReves = jletras.ToString();

      if (p == pAlReves)
      {
        palindromo = false;
      }
    }
    if (palindromo)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("La palabra ingresada no es palíndromo");
    }
    else if (palindromo == false)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("La palabra ingresada si es palíndromo");
    }
  }
}
```

Hola! Como podrán haber visto en el titulo y en mi código, lo que quiero es que me diga en base al input si la palabra ingresada es un palindromo (se lee igual tanto de izquierda a derecha como de derecha a izquierda) Lo que sucede es que siempre me dice, siendo el input un palíndromo o no, que no es. Por qué y como lo arreglo? Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si debuguearas el codigo, te darias cuenta que todo lo que necesitas esta en tu codigo, salvo por un pequeño detalle.

Al hacer esto:

```
for (int j = p.Length-1; j >= 0; j--)
{
  char jletras = Convert.ToChar(p[j]);

  string pAlReves = jletras.ToString();

  if (p == pAlReves)
  {
    palindromo = false;
  }
}
```

Estas invirtiendo la palabra, pero en cada vuelta estas comparando la palabra que vas invirtiendo, con la palabra original.. y obviamente, en la primer vuelta, al no estar completa, ya falla y pone palindromo en false...

Tambien, pAlReves solo tenia la ultima letra... mejor ir agregandole todas las letras ;)

De paso definimos pAlReves afuera del for.. asi no es siempre una variable nueva.

primero, da vuelta la palabra, y luego, compara ;)

```
string pAlReves = ""
for (int j = p.Length-1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    char jletras = Convert.ToChar(p[j]);
    pAlReves += jletras.ToString();
}


  if (p == pAlReves)
  {
    palindromo = false;
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una pregunta,                                                                                                 Al `if (p == pAlReves)
  {
     palindromo = false;
  }`  Da igual ponerlo tanto como dentro como por fuera del for?

Comment: no da igual.. justamente eso hace toda la diferencia.... y eso es lo que esta explicado en mi respuesta.. o eso creia...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **Linq** y hacer una función como esta:

```
public bool EsPalindromo(string texto)
{
   texto = texto.Replace(" ", "");

   var tmp = texto.Reverse();
                          
   return tmp.SequenceEqual(texto);
}
```

Esta función recibe como parámetro el texto a comprobar y una vez dentro de la función se usa el **método Replace** para eliminar los espacios del texto original, posteriormente en la **variable tmp** se invierte el texto usando el **método Reverse** y por último se usa el **método SequenceEqual** el cual compara dos secuencias y devuelve **true** si son iguales, en caso contrario devuelve **false**, te recuerdo que un **string** es un arreglo de caracteres, por tanto un **string** puede decirse que es una secuencia, donde cada elemento de esa secuencia es un tipo **char**.

Para usar la función puedes hacer esto:

```
if (EsPalindromo("anita lava la tina"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Palíndromo");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No es palíndromo");
}
```

Se llama a la función con el texto que deseas comprobar, de retornar **true** se imprime que es palindromo, caso contrario se imprime que no es palindromo.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un poco más de código puedes hacerlo también utilizando una forma que puedes aplicar a otros lenguajes que no contienen Linq implementado. Este es un ejemplo utilizando dos índices que recorren la cadena en direcciones opuestas:

```
    using System;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        static bool EsPalindromo(string s)
        {
            s = s.Replace(" ", "");
            for (int IdxL = 0, IdxR = s.Length - 1; IdxL < IdxR; IdxL++, IdxR--)
            {
                if (s[IdxL] != s[IdxR])
                    return false;
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            string[] Pruebas = {"palíndromo", "cantera verde", "anita lava la tina"};
            
            foreach (string s in Pruebas)
            {
                if (EsPalindromo(s))
                    Console.WriteLine( $"\"{s}\" es palíndromo" );
                else
                    Console.WriteLine( $"\"{s}\" no es palíndromo" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Un buen ejercicio que tendrás para después es encontrar una forma de operar en la función `EsPalindromo(string)` que permita hacer la comprobación *in-situ*, sin necesidad de eliminar los espacios en blanco de la palabra.